# How to make full image path with in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ejs

I am passing value from controller to ejs file with in ajax and accessing that variable with in jquery and passing that variable having image name to next variable with static path of image. So that I can access that variable with in image in JavaScript. Image stored with in folder is of name `Sat Jun 23 2018 12:28:58 GMT+0530 (IST)_2.pn` and while inspecting image I am getting half path which is creating broken image.

Jquery code:

```
var adminimg=$('#adminphoto').val();
    var adminphoto="./uploads/images/"+adminimg;
      mesage_div += "<div class=chat-user-clint><div class=user-image dh ><img src="+adminphoto+"></div><p class=chat-masage id="+onemsg._id+" >"+onemsg.msg_desc+"</p></div><span class='timeago right' title="+onemsg.created_at+"></span><div class=clearfix></div>" ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```js
var adminimg = "Sat Jun 23 2018 12:28:58 GMT+0530 (IST)_2.png";

var adminphoto="./uploads/images/"+adminimg;

// Use EncodeURI or replace to omit spaces
var img_url1 = encodeURI(adminphoto)

var img_url2 = adminphoto.replace(/ /g, '%20')
```

Comment: I have passed this img_url2 its not exactly but working now iam getting url http://localhost:5000/uploads/images/Sat%20Jun%2023%202018%2012:28:58%20GMT%200530%20(IST)_2.png it's again creating broken image. If i remove %20and replace it by +it works how i can do it with in my code.

Comment: Let me know if issue still persist.

Comment: still confused how to replace %20 with + with in whole image path

Comment: You can either use %20 or + in url to get it working. That should not be the issue.

Comment: http://localhost:5000/uploads/images/Sat%20Jun%2023%202018%2012:28:58%20GMT%200530%20(IST)_2.png with in my path at last after 20GMT i want to remove %20 and replace it by + by replacing it in url iam getting exact image.

Comment: Check are you using correct image path in encodeURI or before replace. To only  replace last %20 with + is not correct way, Any correct ASCII encoded URL can be served over HTTP.

Comment: var adminphoto='./uploads/images/'+adminimg;
     var img_url1 = encodeURI(adminphoto);
  

var img_url2 = adminphoto.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    mesage_div += "<div class=chat-user-clint><div class=user-image dh ><img src="+img_url2+"></div><p class=chat-masage id="+onemsg._id+" >"+onemsg.msg_desc+"</p></div><span class='timeago right' title="+onemsg.created_at+"></span><div class=clearfix></div>" ;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173792/discussion-between-abhishek-and-priyanegi).

Comment: Sry! If you're trying to wrap into quotes use this 

mesage_div = "<div class=chat-user-clint><div class=user-image dh ><img src='"+img_url2+"'></div><p class=chat-masage id="+onemsg._id+" >"+onemsg.msg_desc+"</p></div><span class='timeago right' title="+onemsg.created_at+"></span><div class=clearfix></div>"; Use encodeURI and after that you can check it using reverse funct decodeURI to check if your encoding is correct or not.

Comment: when i use to decodeURI it gives http://localhost:5000/uploads/images/Sat i am not getting exact image name

Comment: Can you provide me the full URL, or possible you create plnkr for this ?

Comment: i have passed variable data for image path directly in jquery                       var adminimg='<%=user.photo %>';   its working.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with quotes closing before string end.

**Exampe**

```
var adminimg=$('#adminphoto').val();
var adminphoto="'"+"./uploads/images/"+"'"+adminimg+"'";
  mesage_div += "<div class=chat-user-clint><div class=user-image dh ><img src="+adminphoto+"></div><p class=chat-masage id="+onemsg._id+" >"+onemsg.msg_desc+"</p></div><span class='timeago right' title="+onemsg.created_at+"></span><div class=clearfix></div>" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

The src attribute should not contain space character. Space characters are not allowed in src attribute URLs, you have to encode them. Or rename image when uploading with a valid URLs by replacing space character with underscore.

```
var adminimg=$('#adminphoto').val();
var adminphoto="./uploads/images/"+adminimg;
var adminphoto = adminphoto.split(" ").join("+");
var mesage_div = "<div class=chat-user-clint><div class=user-image dh ><img src="+adminphoto+"></div><p class=chat-masage id= ></p></div><span class='timeago right' title=></span><div class=clearfix></div>" ;
$( "#emoji" ).append( mesage_div );
```

src syntax should be: [valid src Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax)